# Get DocTimeStamped from PDF in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, timestamp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0GtV.png)
In the server, this pdf is timestamped. I want to get the last checked time. It's the DocTimeStamp. My code works for the normal signature but not work with the doc timestamp.

This is my code to get the normal signature:

```
let { PDFDocument, rgb, PDFDict, PDFName, PDFHexString, PDFString } = require('pdf-lib');

const extractSignatureInfo = async (pdfBuf) => {
    console.log('extractSignatureInfo');
    // Load the signed PDF document
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBuf);

    const signatureInfoList = [];
    
    // Iterate through all fields in the document
    const acroFormDict = pdfDoc.context.lookup(pdfDoc.catalog.get(PDFName.of('AcroForm')));
    
    if (acroFormDict){
        const fieldsArray = acroFormDict.get(PDFName.of('Fields')).asArray();

        for (const fieldRef of fieldsArray) {
            const field = pdfDoc.context.lookup(fieldRef); // Use lookup to get the actual PDFRef
            const fieldType = field.get(PDFName.of('FT'))?.asString();

            if (fieldType === '/Sig') {
                const signatureDictRef = field.get(PDFName.of('V'));
                const signatureDict = pdfDoc.context.lookup(signatureDictRef); // Use lookup for the signatureDict
        
                if (signatureDict instanceof PDFDict) {
                    const signatureInfo = {
                        fieldName: field.get(PDFName.of('T'))?.asString(),
                        certificateName: signatureDict.get(PDFName.of('Name'))?.toString(),
                        signingTime: signatureDict.get(PDFName.of('M'))?.toString(),
                    };

                    let reason = signatureDict.get(PDFName.of('Reason'))
                    if (reason instanceof PDFString) {
                        reason = decodeUTF16BE(reason) || reason.asString('utf-8');
                    }
                    signatureInfo.reason = reason;
        
                    signatureInfoList.push(signatureInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    return signatureInfoList;
}
```

---

Comment: *"I want to get the last checked time."* - The last checked time is the time at which the application displaying that time last validated the signature in question.. Thus, if your application also validates the signature, simply display the time of the recent validation thereof. If your application does not validate the signature, there is no sensible time to use as last checked time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timestamp for last checked to get.

It is the time when you run any app on a validation computer, so NOT accessible in or by the PDF it does not know what computer it will be run in. Depending on the App it cold be worded differently.

[image]

Here I open it 10.5 mins later in Acrobat which auto checks and it adds its clock time to the Acrobat version of its dialog. I did not ask that the time be updated as there is no time to update.

Basically either scrape the screen data or look at the system clock or find where the time is in computer memory.

[image]

Just be aware you cannot trust any PDF visual representation of time as Instreams "Theory of Relativity" postdates H G Wells' use of Time Machines.

[image]
[image]